# Imprimir array num ficheiro

Tags: php

Estou a inserir dados de uma base de dados sqlite, num ficheiro. Crio o ficheiro com um nome que o utilizador escolhe, e insiro todos os dados da tabela.

O problema é que só insere no ficheiro uma linha da tabela, enquanto que existem mais linhas na tabela. E repete 2 vezes os campos.

```
$base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
$requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY id desc";   
$resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
$affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();// 
$nombreid = $affiche['id'];

$fp = fopen($namefile.'.csv', 'w');
$list = array();

for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
    {       
        $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i)";  
        $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    // 
        $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();//


        $list = $affiche;
    }

fputcsv($fp,$list,$delimiter = ';');

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema original do tópico, de ter apenas uma linha da tabela sendo inserida, ocorre porque nesse trecho do código:

```
for( $i=1; $i <= $nombreid; $i++ ) {       

    // ...

    $list = $affiche; <--
}
```

A cada iteração feita a variável é sobrescrita com os resultados da query feita dentro do loop.

E como variáveis definidas num bloco de iteração não são eliminadas após o término da mesma, o fputcsv() invocado fora do loop usa aquilo que tem.

Resta, então, invocar a função dentro do loop como sugerido pelo @Jorge B., o que conforme os comentários produz uma repetição indesejada.

Eu acredito que isso esteja acontecendo por causa do seu for-loop que está definido de uma forma meio sem lógica (do ponto de visto externo, afinal não conheço sua Aplicação).

Numa leitura "normal" do recurso retornado por [SQLite3Result::fetchArray()](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) você teria algo assim:

```
while( $list = $resultat -> fetchArray() ) {

    // Do somethng
}
```

Invocar fputcsv() ali dentro, por is só, já funcionaria, porém ainda com resultados duplicados.

Essa duplicidade ocorre porque, não sei por qual motivo, funções de *fetching* de dados mantém, até hoje, retorno de dados de dois modos: indexado e associativo.

No caso da SQLIte, o valor padrão SQLITE3_BOTH faz com aquele **$list** seja algo assim:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => int 1
  'id' => int 1
  1 => string 'Bruno' (length=5)
  'name' => string 'Bruno' (length=5)
  2 => int 26
  'age' => int 26
```

Definir manualmente outro modo de retorno, associativo por exemplo (SQLITE3_ASSOC), já resolve **esse** problema de duplicidade.

Perceba que eu destaque **esse** problema de duplicidade porque, sem conhecer sua Aplicação, você inflige outra duplicidade, talvez, sem querer por causa do seu for-loop mal definido.

Isso:

```
$nombreid = $affiche['id'];

// ...

for( $i = 1; $i <= $nombreid; $i++ ) {

    // Do something
}
```

Vai **repetir** TODA instrução do loop tantas vezes quantas o ponteiro for testado positivamente como sendo menor ou igual a **$nombreid**.

Analise seu comentário na resposta do Jorge B. Você tem dois registros no banco mais o comportamento padrão da SQLITE3 já faria com que você tivesse 4 entradas no seu CSV.

Mas vamos imaginar que essa variável tenha como valor **3**, afinal ela vêm de um ID e **3** é um ID válido. Isso, com a atual definição do seu for-loop, faria a instrução toda se repetir 3 vezes.

Caso você **não** estivesse fazendo outra query dentro desse loop, você teria **12** entradas (2 * 2 * 3), mas já que está, você está repetindo a duplicidade da SQLITE3 três vezes e, por isso, seis entradas no CSV.

Enfim, como sempre, a solução mais simples é a mais correta:

```
$resultat   =   $base_hndl -> query( $requete );

$fp = fopen( $namefile . 'csv', 'w' );

while( $list = $resultat -> fetchArray( SQLITE3_ASSOC ) ) {
    fputcsv( $fp, $list, $delimiter = ';' );
}

fclose( $fp );
```

Para fins de teste você pode querer reconstruir esse CSV num array para visualizar melhor. No manual tem [uma funçãozinha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#100593) legal que te permite isso.

Answer (score 0):

Isso é porque estás a gravar fora do ciclo `for`, basta gravares dentro:

```
$base_hndl  =   new SQLite3($dir.$base);
$requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact ORDER BY id desc";   
$resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete);    
$affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray(); 
$nombreid = $affiche['id'];

$fp = fopen($namefile.'.csv', 'w');
$list = array();

for($i=1;$i<=$nombreid;$i++)
{       
    $requete    =   "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE (id=$i)";  
    $resultat   =   $base_hndl->query($requete); 
    $affiche    =   $resultat->fetchArray();

    $list = $affiche;

    fputcsv($fp,$list,$delimiter = ';');//<----------------DENTRO DO CICLO
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Certo, e porque repete duas vezes no ficheiro os campos da tabela, ou seja 1;1;abar;abar;ddd;ddd. São 3 campos, e aparacem 6.

Comment: Isso deve ser porque deves ter 6 id no Banco de Dados.

Comment: Não, tenho apenas 2 registos.

Comment: E esses 2 registos que id têm?

Comment: Tem id 1 e id 2

Comment: Estive a ver o http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php e tens de fazer `$nombreid = $affiche[0]['id'];` para obter o primeiro id.